# Marginal densities of same SDE with different initial distributions

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck SDE:
$$dX_t=-\gamma_t X_t dt + \sigma_t dB_t$$
where $\gamma_t$ and $\sigma_t$ are time-varying constants independent of $X_t$. Now assume I have two versions of the SDE with the only thing different being the initial distributions, $\hat{X}_0 \sim p_0(\hat{X})$ and $\tilde{X}_0 \sim q_0(\tilde{X})$. All else are the same.

Is there any relation I can write down between the marginal densities along the paths, $p_t(\hat{X})$ and $q_t(\tilde{X})$ that is related to how far apart the initial distributions are, for e.g., in terms of $D_{KL}(p_0||q_0)$? Intuitively (correct me if I'm wrong), the farther apart the initial distributions, the farther apart their marginals should be?

I was thinking along the lines of computing the ratio $p_t/q_t$, or equivalently the Radon-Nikodym derivative $dP/dQ$ via Girsanov's theorem, which would require me to transform one measure to the other, but I'm not sure if that's the right approach since the SDEs have identical forms.

Thank you very much! I'm a total newbie in stochastic calculus so please forgive me for my poor notations/reasoning.

Comment: The OU process has an explicit transition density: https://web.math.ku.dk/~susanne/StatDiff/Overheads1b.pdf https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/245120/transition-density-and-distribution-ornstein-uhlenbeck-process, so you can try comparing those two Gaussian like densities.

Comment: @ThomasKojar thanks for the suggestion. I can do something like $p(x_t) = \int p(x_t|x_0) p(x_0) dx_0$, where $p(x_t|x_0)$ is the Gaussian transition density of OU. However this doesn't really reduce to a nice form for a downstream problem. Was wondering if there is a way to use Girsanov to transform measures where the difference is only the starting distributions.

Comment: As $X_t = f(t)\cdot X_0 + g(t)$, I suggest that you compute the density function of $\hat {X}_t - \bar{X}_t = f(t) \cdot(\hat {X}_0 - \bar{X}_0 ) $